# Virtualenv and anaconda conflict

Tags: python

I've installed Anaconda recently. I have an virtual environment I am using for one of my projects. I try to activate it:

```
(vierualenv)Ilyas-Air-4:data_analysis ilyalapan$ source vierualenv/bin/activate
(vierualenv)Ilyas-Air-4:data_analysis ilyalapan$ which python
/anaconda/bin/python
```

But which python returns me anaconda executable. Why could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized that this happened because my virtualenv was 2.7 environment.

```
which python2
```

gave me the right python executable